# How to add object in Array of Objects using Node js in Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to update my `courseModules` inside `MasterCourse`. In below JSON I have two Objects in `courseModules`. I want if `moduleId` exist in `courseModules` then update it else create a new object and return the `courseModules` with updated value.
I am using Node js and mondodb, mongoose. Not able to find how can I achieve this functionality.

JSON OR MONGODB Data:

```
"MasterCourse": [
{
    "_id": "6392f2611e7d670eca9712fa",
    "courseTitle": "My Course Title",
    "awardURL": "award.png",
    "courseModules": [
        {
            "moduleId": 0,
            "moduleTitle": "Module Title 1",
            "moduleDescription": "Module 1 description",
            "totalSessions": 3,
            "_id": "6392f2611e7d670eca97e12d"
        },
        {
            "moduleId": 1,
            "moduleTitle": "ModuleTitle 2",
            "moduleDescription": "Module 2 description",
            "totalSessions": 4,
            "_id": "6392f2611e7d670eca9711wd"
        },
    ],
}
```

]

Query want to perform:

```
{
    "moduleId": 2,
    "moduleTitle": "Module Title 3",
    "moduleDescription": "Module 3 description",
    "totalSessions": 8,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add if item not exist -

```
masterCourse.updateOne({ "_id": req.params.id }, { $addToSet: { "courseModules": req.body } })
```

To update the value if exist -

```
 masterCourse.updateOne({ "_id": req.params.id, "courseModules._id": ModuleID }, { $set: { "courseModules": req.body } })
```

These queries works for me, you can change the variable's name according to your data or requirement.